# Missing CSRF token in REST request

Tags: spring, rest, csrf

I'm writing a REST API using Spring MVC. I'm trying to access a controller method via a POST request.

I always receive a `403`error:

```
Invalid CSRF Token '' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.
```

How can I deliver a CSRF token within my REST request?
I tried to use the `default security password` which is displayed during application startup as the value for `_csrf` but it wasn't successful.

How can I retrieve the CSRF token and is it correct to send the token in the `_csrf` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to provide the correct header and CSRF token when making the request e.g.

```
request.setRequestHeader('${_csrf.headerName}', '${_csrf.token}');
```

You can also send the token as a request parameter using `_csrf.parameterName`.

Comment: Okay, but I don't get it how to retrieve the token?

Comment: You can embed the token using `${_csrf.token}` anywhere in your document (meta tag, javascript variable, etc.). Be sure the filter used by Spring Security is applied

Comment: Maybe I'm getting *retrieve* argument wrong. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: No that's fine! I've put the token into the <meta> tags! Thank you!